# How to display an HTML file in UITextView if I don't have nstring to display it directly?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

Does anyone know to to display a `HTML` file correctly in a `UITextView`? Currently I am able to display the file in the view but I am not able to encode the HTML so that the tags do not appear in the view. Below is the code that I am using to call the file in the `UITextView`

```
if let filepath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "test", ofType: "html") {  
            do {  
                let contents = try String(contentsOfFile: filepath)  
                print(contents)  
                TextView.text = contents  

            } catch {  
                /  
            }  
        } else {  
            /  
        }
```

Comment: @RajeshKumarR that code described to display html file in webview we need it in uitextview

Comment: @RajeshKumarR see the code they have nstring instead of i have html file so how to there could be another way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get data from the string and use [init(data:options:documentAttributes:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsattributedstring/1524613-init)
 method to generate the attributed string.

```
if let filepath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "test", ofType: "html") {
    if let htmlString = try? String(contentsOfFile: filepath, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8), let data = htmlString.data(using: String.Encoding.unicode) {
        let attString = try? NSAttributedString(data: data, options: [NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey.documentType : NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html], documentAttributes: nil)
        textView.attributedText = attString
    }
}
```